# What is the difference between ODI on marketplace or on premise?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

What’s the difference between ODI on marketplace or on premise?  What exactly is ODI on marketplace?
Some experts told me that On Cloud the focus is on ODI on Marketplace.
On premise, ODI is based on many other products like OBIA, FDMEE, Hyperion Planning.
I wanted to learn the difference  in simple layman terms as I am not familiar with products like OBIA, FDMEE, Hyperion Planning.

As per my research on this area , there  are some cloud products -like  ODICS, DIPC, DIPC Classic.

I am curious to know weather ODI on Marketplace will have all equivalent functionalities which are offered through ODICS, DIPC, DIPC Classic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer : I'm an Oracle employee*

ODI on Marketplace is basically a compute instance (VM in the cloud) where ODI is pre-installed. It has the same functionalities as ODI on premise. It also comes with a mysql database on the VM to hold the repository if that option has been chosen during provisioning. Alternatively the repository can be created on an existing Autonomous Database. The cost of the service is only the price of the compute instance. At the moment ODI on Marketplace doesn't require a license if the target is an Autonomous Database or a DBaaS on OCI. If the target is another technology, a license (same as on-prem license) is required and has to be acquired separately.

---

```
On premise, ODI is based on many other products like OBIA, FDMEE, Hyperion Planning.
```

This is the other way around. ODI is a tool on it's own. OBIA and FDMEE are two products that are using ODI to extract data from specific Apps and load it into a data warehouse.

---

```
As per my research on this area , there are some cloud products -like ODICS, DIPC, DIPC Classic.
```

These services are not strategic products anymore so it is not possible to provision new instances of it. ODI on marketplace as similar functionalities as ODICS. DIPC Classic and DIPC could also include Oracle GoldenGate and Oracle Enterprise Data Quality features depending on the edition that was chosen (Strandard, Enterprise or Governance). If these features are needed to these are GoldenGate on Marketplace and EDQ on Marketplace.

There is another product called OCI Data Integration being release soon so check the news for webinars in the coming weeks.

[EDIT] OCI Data Integration has been released in June 2020. It allows to build serverless integration jobs in the Cloud